# Android browser: cancel CSS :hover state when replacing page contents in a click() handler

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

On Android browser, when I click an element which handler replaces (part of) the page contents, any **new** element that is beneath the exact spot where I clicked is considered in hover state even though I released the click.

Note that only the `hover` CSS state is concerned, `focus` or `active` don't exhibit this behaviour.

Here is some minimal example code that reproduces my issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toButton() {
      document.getElementById("body").innerHTML =
                            '<input type="button" onclick="toLink()" value="Click me!">';
    }
    function toLink() {
      document.getElementById("body").innerHTML =
                            '<a href="javascript:toButton()">Click me!</a>';
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body * { font-size: 400%; }
    input { color: black; }
    input:hover { color: red; }
    a { color: blue; }
    a:hover { color: red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
  <script type="text/javascript">toButton();</script>
</body></html>
```

And some screenshots to make it easier to understand:

[image: Example]

The `2. Hovering` is perfectly normal, but as you can see `3. After click` believes the link is still being hovered, when in reality it is not and should display as `4. Expected`.

Note that if the button's text is made wider (eg. `Click on my very left side to trigger the problem`), clicking on `Click on` will trigger the problem while clicking on `very left side to trigger the problem` will not.

---

**Is there a way to force the browser to recompute the hover state, or otherwise cancel it?** If possible it should not modify a specific element (ie. the link, in my example) but act on a global level so that every element of the page is protected from that bug (I have lots of elements that are impacted, and adding handlers to every single one would be a real pain so I really need a page-wide solution).

Despite my example not using it in order to isolate the problem, I actually use jQuery so solutions using it are welcome.

I am testing this on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 / Android 4.1, if that's important.

Comment: you don't need document.all for anything to anyone these days. you can hide and shortly thereafter (~30ms) unhide the hovered element to kill the :hover.

Comment: @dandavis OK. I actually use jQuery selectors, but I wanted to make an example that only uses standard browser features so I grabbed this `elemById` part on the web without thinking about it. Fixed.

Comment: @dandavis Your hiding/showing suggestion kinda works, but on my application it needs a 500ms timeout in order to be effective, which makes a weird flickering effect. So I'd rather use a solution not involving timers, if possible. Still you should post this as an answer, I'd accept that if nobody comes up with something better.

Comment: you can likely use https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick to get that delay well under 500ms...

Comment: @dandavis Looked like a good idea at first, but it doesn't change anything, I still need the 500ms delay. I also tried `user-scalable=no` in `<meta viewport>` to no avail, so it seems that delay is unrelated to the double-tap-to-zoom feature (which makes sense actually: I start the timer inside the click handler, but the double-tap-to-zoom has to be handled before the click event is generated).

Comment: maybe a full-screen clear div over the body would break the hover, i've used that trick on the desktop when simply hiding it temporarily was a poor option.

Comment: @dandavis A div over the whole page has no effect on the hover state, whatever delay I use. I also tried various other variations (other element types, adding a :hover CSS rule for the covering element), no luck either. Never mind, for now I'm fading out the page to white before starting the 500ms delay, which makes the screen flickering seem much more natural and rather bearable, I'll make do with it until I can find a solution that doesn't involve timers. Thanks a bunch for your help and your patience!

Comment: not all the old tricks work on mobile, sometimes a re-shaping is easier than moving heaven and earth...